# Architecture of c++ projects

Tags: c++

I am from JAVA so please please guide me if i am wrong.

In Java we mostly use a singleton class and create all the class objects thought the singleton class.

What about in c++?

I know we can use singleton but mostly while going through most of the stack overflow questions. Most of them says it's not good to use singleton in c++

Can you recommend some book or some project which will be easy to understand?

Comment: Way too broad a topic to deal with on S.O.

Comment: "....we mostly use a singleton class and create all the class objects thought the singleton class...." - are you referring to a bean factory for a dependency injection engine?

Comment: The factory factory paradigm is not a plus for Java either.

Comment: Large Scale C++ Software Design by Lakos is a quite old, but fabulous.

Comment: Just to note this isn't a good question for stack overflow. The [question asking for books](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1084416) is still there but only because it's so useful, not because it fits SO format well.

Answer (score 2):

Whether you're writing in C++ or Java singletons have [many](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SingletonsAreEvil),  [bad implications](http://blogs.msdn.com/scottdensmore/archive/2004/05/25/140827.aspx).

They make it very difficult to test as their static nature preculdes late binding to, say, sway a real database with a stub that's quicker and has fewer depencies.

They also provide a fig leaf for global variables, trying to make them masquerade as a good design decision. Take a look at the alternatives, it'll pay off in a better design. You may want to look into [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) for ways to design a more testable system without singletons.

Comment: This should be a comment. You are not answering his question.

Comment: Perhaps the 'correct me if I'm wrong' portion of the question? What about in c++.